# import csv file mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js

want to save csv file in mongodb with node js i used javascript to to add and fetch data but it get error
get('/import', function(req, res, next) {

```
var  stocks1  = [];

var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){

      // var errorCount = 0;
      // var csvStream = csv.parse({strictColumnHandling: true, headers: true}) .on("data", function(data){

     
     var item = new Stock({
      Diamondcode: data[0],
      Sortdesc: data[1],
      Colour:  data[2],
      Size: data[3],
      Meserment:data[4] ,
      Price:data[5]
     });
     
      item.save(function(error){
        console.log(item);
          if(error){
               throw error;
          }
      }); 
}).on("end", function(){
      console.log(" End of file import");
});

// stream.pipe(csvStream);
res.json({success : "Data imported successfully.", status : 200});
```

}).get('/fetchdata', function(req, res, next) {

```
Stock.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (!err){ 
        res.json({success : "Updated Successfully", status : 200, data: docs});
    } else { 
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you haven't given the path of your CSV. One traditional way I used in my node projects as
kept route file different and pass your csv file in form data and then access it as req.files.

**Make sure you create a wrapper for your CSV conversion**